# Understanding of Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

I have been watching videos from 3Blue1brown guy on youtube. He explains that the fourier transform is an unscaled version of calculating the centre of mass of a graph.

ref:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY

But I don't think the intuition is correct because $g(t)e^{-iwt}$ refers to the original graph
Whereas $g(t)$ should be the winded or augmented graph if you want to calculate the centre of mass.

g(t) is the unknown graph

w = 2*pi*f

In his video he explaains that given an unknown graph, you winded it around a circle and then calculate the frequency of the winded graph. When the frequency fo that graph matches the frequency of the unknown graph the centre of mass deviates from the origin.

Has anyone heard this intuition before?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbJJ1.png)

Comment: welcome to math stackexchange! in the future, please take a few minutes to learn how to use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make you posts easier to read. I've taken the liberty of making of a first edit for you along those lines. in addition, your question is a bit light on context; most people will not have the time to go through and watch the video you are referring to, so you're more likely to get an answer if you include more details about the question yourself. for instance, what are $g(t)$ and $w$?

Comment: w = 2pif and g(t) is an unknown graph

Comment: Anyone? this si the video btw https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY